# Is it possible to change sended email content before someone reading it?

Tags: email

My question is about email content modification. I have a email content like this : `"User xxx13247923612 current changed +712.96EUR Delivered: John Smith Free credit: 11090.88EUR"`.

I want to change the content to this `"Current changed +712.96EUR Delivered: John Smith"`, before employees see this email.

Im using my own email domain (user@example.com) IMAP. Using Roundcube as email client and Postfixadmin for administration.

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: But if it's too yourself you could forward the email - with correction - on, then delete old version.